# Django-stripe-paymants and eldarion-ajax subscribe JSON response

Tags: ajax, json, django, stripe-payments, eldarion-ajax

I am working with Django-stripe-paymants and it's working except for handling the JSON response after the subscribe form is completed. They payment is processed and the web hooks look good.

But it is just showing the JSON is browser window.

ie:

```
{"html": "\n\n\n<div class=\"subscribe-form\">\n    <h2>Purchase a Subscription.....
```

I imagine there is something small missing in the Java script, but am stuck.

I have read through the documentation a few times and searched around for a solution. The common cause for this was not including bootstrap-ajax.js. Since the last relevant issue I can find, bootstrap-ajax has been renamed eldarion-ajax.

My base template includes:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/vendor/checkout.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/vendor/eldarion-ajax.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Any pointers will be appreciated. Javascript is not my strong point..

Thanks!

Comment: There are are some undocumented requirements with this package. I have installed it within the 'pinax' framework and the redirect works from the json response.

Comment: This ended up being a jquery problem. I moved to 1.9.1 and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realise it looks like you've figured out an answer to your own question, however I had a very similar issue with my Django-stripe-payments + eldarion-ajax app and I managed to get jQuery v1.11.0 to work ok.  Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494604/django-ajax-json-response-appears-as-raw-text-in-browser) for my answer.