# Django AJAX JSON response appears as raw text in browser

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, json, django

I'm developing a Stripe webapp using Django (1.4.2) inside a Pinax framework and with:

1. django-stripe-payments
2. eldarion-ajax

I've got everything working except the ajax response (in JSON format) doesn't appear to be processed by any ajax callbacks, and hence appears as raw JSON data in the browser:

```
{"html": "\n\n<div class=\"change-card\">\n    <h2>Current Card</h2>\n    <p class=\"lead\">\n        \n            Current card on file is a <strong>Visa</strong>\n            ending in the digits <strong>4242</strong>.\n        \n    </p>\n    \n    \n    \n    <form action=\"/payments/a/change/card/\" data-stripe-key=\"\" class=\"form ajax\" data-replace-closest=\".change-card\" method=\"POST\">\n        <div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='<>' /></div>\n        <input name=\"stripe_token\" type=\"hidden\" />\n        <a href=\"\" class=\"btn btn-primary change-card\">Change Card</a>\n    </form>\n</div>\n"}
```

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21774731/django-stripe-paymants-and-eldarion-ajax-subscribe-json-response) seems to be similar, but there is no official answer, and the submitter seems to have figured it out (going by the comments), but the suggestions don't work for me.

Details:

I'm using `python manage.py runserver` within both Chrome and Firefox to test.

I'm just getting started with the stripe app, and have just used the examples from django-stripe-payments to get going before I tailor for my specific needs.

My test case that I'm running involves using the standard ajax form from django-stripe-payments to change the stored credit card:

```
<form action="{% url 'payments_ajax_change_card' %}" data-stripe-key="{{ STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY }}" class="form ajax" data-replace-closest=".change-card" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="stripe_token" type="hidden" />
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary change-card">{% if request.user.customer.card_kind %}Change{% else %}Add{% endif %} Card</a>
</form>
```

There is some javascript in my base template that gets called and displays the form from stripe to enter the card details - when the "change card" button is selected.  I don't think this is at fault - I took it straight from [here](http://django-stripe-payments.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#static-media).

I have the following above that function:

```
<script src="{% static "js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" %}"></script>
<script src="//checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js"></script>
```

and this below

```
<script src="{% static "js/eldarion-ajax.min.js" %}"></script>
```

Following the return of the token (and the subsequent form submit event) the following view code is executed:

```
@require_POST
@login_required
def change_card(request):
    try:
        customer = request.user.customer
        send_invoice = customer.card_fingerprint == ""
        customer.update_card(
            request.POST.get("stripe_token")
        )
        if send_invoice:
            customer.send_invoice()
        customer.retry_unpaid_invoices()
        data = {}
    except stripe.CardError, e:
        data = {"error": e.message}
    return _ajax_response(request, "payments/_change_card_form.html", **data)
```

Again... this is out-of-the-box django-stripe-payment code.  The next thing that happens is the raw JSON as mentioned above.

Comment: Well in that answer provided he said it ended up being a jQuery problem.  Which version of jQuery is your app using?

Comment: I did put that in there, but obviously not clear enough - v1.9.1.  I also tried 1.11.0 and 1.8.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it.  It turned out it was indeed a jQuery problem.  I was referencing two jQuery files in my application. When I removed the second one, and stuck with the one mentioned in the question above, it worked!  My credit card details updated as expected on the page (albeit slowly).

Because I am using the pinax framework, it comes with a jquery reference automatically.  It's required for the Django debug toolbar at least.This is included in the "base.html" file inside:

```
{% block script_base %}{% endblock %}
```

("base.html" is located here: pinax_theme_bootstrap/templates/theme_bootstrap)

Fortunately base.html provides an over-ridable block called "jquery_src", so in my "site_base.html" file in my app, I just entered the following towards the bottom:

```
{% block jquery_src %}{% endblock %}
```

This removed the second jQuery library.

I also tried using jQuery v1.11.0 which was thought to be at fault in [this SO question I mentioned earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21774731/django-stripe-paymants-and-eldarion-ajax-subscribe-json-response) and it also worked.