# Django-Stripe-Payments dumps Json to browser on post

Tags: jquery, python, django, stripe-payments, eldarion-ajax

So I'm having a similar problem to [Django AJAX JSON response appears as raw text in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494604/django-ajax-json-response-appears-as-raw-text-in-browser)  or [Django-stripe-paymants and eldarion-ajax subscribe JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21774731/django-stripe-paymants-and-eldarion-ajax-subscribe-json-response?rq=1) but I can't find this second reference to jQuery and I've also tried multiple versions of jQuery. Their payment is processed and the web hooks look good just like them.

I haven't gotten any help so far but I could probably solve my problem with any of the following:

1. other reference repositories of people using django-stripe-payments
2. A walk though of how to get django-stripe-payments workings because the requirements page is not enough so far.

I've created a bare essentials version needed for the stock version django-stripe-payments to work and the problem still persists.

I created a virtualenv and pip installed django, then django-stripe-payments and django-forms-bootstrap.  Those installs included both django-jsonfield and stripe.  So pip shows I have the following

```
Django==1.6.5
argparse==1.2.1
django-forms-bootstrap==3.0.0
django-jsonfield==0.9.13
django-stripe-payments==2.0b34
pytz==2014.4
requests==2.3.0
stripe==1.19.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

My site_base.html is

```
<script src="/static/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js"></script> 

<script>
$(function() {
    $('body').on("click", '.change-card, .subscribe-form button[type=submit]', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $form = $(this).closest("form"),
          token = function(res) {
            $form.find("input[name=stripe_token]").val(res.id);
            $form.trigger("submit");
          };

      StripeCheckout.open({
        key:         $form.data("stripe-key"),
        name:        'Payment Method',
        panelLabel:  'Add Payment Method',
        token:       token
      });

      return false;
    });
});
</script>

{% block title %}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
{% endblock %}

<script src="static/js/eldarion-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

when I try and change a payment plan I get the proper GET but on the post I believe it isn't linking with jQuery

```
[20/Aug/2014 20:06:33] "GET /payments/change/plan/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2063
[20/Aug/2014 20:06:33] "GET /payments/change/plan/static/js/eldarion-ajax.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 4139
[20/Aug/2014 20:06:37] "POST /payments/a/change/plan/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1394
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure now that it has something to do with the django admin https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/ it says To avoid conflicts with user-supplied scripts or libraries, Django’s jQuery (version 1.9.1) is namespaced as django.jQuery. If you want to use jQuery in your own admin JavaScript without including a second copy, you can use the django.jQuery object on changelist and add/edit views.  Which would explain why someone had a conflict when using jqueery 1.11.1 instead of 1.9.1.  But I can't find out how to make the fix knowing this information.

Answer (score 0):

This is because it's designed to work with http://github.com/eldarion/eldarion-ajax (or your own AJAX handling.